# Kendo grid CRUD doesn't persist in the server side

Tags: javascript, node.js, kendo-ui

The create method sends "null" values, the delete method returns a 404 not found, and the put method only clears the edited field. (all methods are working in postman).

I'm not sure how Kendo UI sends the to the API, but my create method waits for the parameters in the body, the delete method waits for the id in the URL(localhost:3000/api/comment/32). My put method also waits for parameters in the body (JSON).

I'm probably doing something wrong, but I don't know what it is.

Here is the code and the screens (the screen is from the post method):

[image]

[image]

```js
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>Kendo UI Snippet</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.common.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.default.mobile.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.rtl.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/kendo.silver.min.css">
    <script src="js/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/pako_deflate.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jszip.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/estilo.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/daterangepicker.css">

  </head>
  <body>
   
<div id="example">
    <div id="gridComment"></div>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            
          var commentDataSource = new kendo.data.DataSource({
            //autoSync : true,
            transport: {
                            read:{
                                url: "http://localhost:3000/api/comment",
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "get",
                                //contentType: "application/json"
                            },
                            update: {
                                url: "http://localhost:3000/api/comment",
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "put",
                                //contentType: "application/json"
                            },
                            create: {
                                url: "http://localhost:3000/api/comment",
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "post",
                            },
                            destroy: {
                                url: "http://localhost:3000/api/comment",
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "delete",
                                //contentType: "application/json"
                            },
                            
                        },
                        schema:{
                            type: "json",
                            model:{
                                id: "idvatc",
                                fields:{
                                    idvatc: { type: "number", editable : false},
                                    commen: { nullable: true},
                                }   
                            }
                        },
                        batch: true,

          })

             $("#gridComment").kendoGrid({
                    dataSource : commentDataSource,
                    editable: true,
                    confirmation: false,
                    toolbar: ["save", "cancel","create"],
                    columns : [{
                        field : "commen",
                        title : "Comment"
                    },
                    { command: ["edit","destroy"], title: "Actions", width: 200 }
                    ],
                    

                });


        });

        
    </script>

    
</div>


    

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I think I see your problem. Kendo is sending a `application/x-www-url-formencoded` content type and I'm guessing your endpoint only accepts `application/json`. Two solutions, either make your endpoint accept `x-www-url-formencoded` or prefilter the Ajax request before it is sent.

Haven't done any Nodejs work so I can't offer pointers. However, if your endpoint is Java, in Spring it was simply removing the `@ResponseBody` annotation.

Next option is to prefilter the Ajax request. This example modifies the URL, so this could work in your Delete method. First off is modifying your `transport` to something like so:

```
transport: {
    read: {
        url: url,
        contentType: 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: options.httpRequestType,
        beforeSend: beforeSend, // function to call before sending the request
        data: function(data) {
            if (options.httpRequestType === 'POST') {
                return {
                    preFilterMe: true,
                    parameters: options.parameters,
                    page: data.page,
                    itemsPerPage: data.pageSize,
                };
            }

            return {
                page: data.page,
                itemsPerPage: data.pageSize,
            };
        },
    },
},
```

In the above example, if the request is a POST, it returns more data to be used in prefiltering.

Here I change the URL and put the JSON data in the body if it is a POST and prefilter is `true`.

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, xhr) {
    if (originalOptions.type === 'POST' && 
        originalOptions.data.preFilterMe) {
        
        options.url = options.url + '?page=' + originalOptions.data.page
            + '&itemsPerPage=' + originalOptions.data.itemsPerPage;

        if (originalOptions.data.parameters.length > 0) {
            options.data = JSON.stringify(originalOptions.data.parameters);
        }
    }
});
```

Hope this example will guide you to a solution.

Comment: Hi @jpllosa, thanks again for your help. Sorry for the delayed response. I tried your example here (http://dojo.telerik.com/ecAKIqed), changing the code of the example that you kindly provided. Still, I am getting an error (last picture in the question) with options not defined... I'm also trying to fix on the server-side to accept URL encoded but without success. Again thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: Your DOJO example is completely wrong and how can I possibly connect to `localhost:3000`. Please read jQuery API for more details about `beforeSend` and `$.ajaxPrefilter`. Actually, you probably don't need a `beforeSend`. The point of the example is you can change the URL from the client side so that the backend can understand it. Also, this example is hitting my endpoint and not yours. Can your endpoint understand `itemsPerPage`? This is meant to be a guide and definitely is not a copy-paste solution to your problem.

Comment: Yes, I know that you cannot access my localhost:3000. I just sent the dojo to show what I was doing. I will read the jquery API documentation as you suggested. Sorry for the inconvenience, and again thanks for your help and patience.

Comment: @Researcher no worries. Hope the example gave you and idea on how to solve your problem.

Comment: Yes It's helping me thanks to your example I'm already fixed the delete operation, since my back end waits for a '/:id' i just did the following: 
                            destroy: {
                                url: function(data){
                                    return url_d + '/' + data.models[0]["idvatc"]; 
                                },
                                dataType: "json",
                                type: "DELETE"  
                            },
When i finish the PUT and POST i will send here If someone may need it. Again many thanks.